# How do I stop accessing class variables and instead access an instance variable?

Tags: python, class, class-variables

given the following code:

```
class GridSpace:
    space = "e"

class GridRow:  
    space1 = GridSpace()
    space2 = GridSpace()
    space3 = GridSpace()
    space4 = GridSpace()
    space5 = GridSpace()
    space6 = GridSpace()
    space7 = GridSpace()
    space8 = GridSpace()
    space9 = GridSpace()
    space10 = GridSpace()
    spaceList = [space1, space2, space3, space4, space5, space6, space7, space8, space9, space10]

class Grid:    
    gridRow1 = GridRow()
    gridRow2 = GridRow()
    gridRow3 = GridRow()
    gridRow4 = GridRow()
    gridRow5 = GridRow()
    gridRow6 = GridRow()
    gridRow7 = GridRow()
    gridRow8 = GridRow()
    gridRow9 = GridRow()
    gridRow10 = GridRow()
    rowList = [gridRow1, gridRow2, gridRow3, gridRow4, gridRow5, gridRow6, gridRow7, gridRow8, gridRow9, gridRow10]

grid = Grid()

grid.rowList[0].spaceList[0].space = "s"

for x in grid.rowList:
    rowWord = ""
    for y in x.spaceList:
        rowWord = rowWord + y.space + " "
    print(rowWord)
```

I want to output a 10x10 grid of the e character, except the top left character which is supposed to be an s character. What instead happens is I am changing the class variable for the first element of every row list, instead of the instance variable of the first element of only the first row list. How do I make it change only the very first character into an s, and leave the other 99 characters an e?

Comment: You can use for loops to create your lists of GridRow and GridSpace objects.

Comment: You've **only** created class variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the following statement is `True`

```
grid = Grid()
print(Grid.rowList[0].spaceList[0] is Grid.rowList[1].spaceList[0]) # outputs True
```

Here you can see that the First row's `spaceList[0]` is the exact same as the second row's `spaceList[0]` (they are referring to the same object and when one is changed the other is as well).

As you have already somehow guessed, you need to turn these into **instance** variables. But you'll have to do this 2 level deeps, meaning you'll have to apply this to both `GridSpace` and `GridRow`

```
class GridSpace:
    def __init__(self):
        self.space = "e" # Now "e" is unique to every column
```

As well as

```
class GridRow:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.spaceList = [GridSpace() for _ in range(10)]
```

Now the statement `print(Grid.rowList[0].spaceList[0] is Grid.rowList[1].spaceList[0])` is indeed `False` and your code runs fine

```
s e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e 
e e e e e e e e e e
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variables to be instance variables you have to define them so (e.g. in `__init__` function by using `self` parameter):

```
class GridSpace:
    def __init__(self):
        self.space = "e"

class GridRow: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.spaceList = [GridSpace() for i in range(10)]

class Grid:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.rowList = [GridRow() for i in range(10)]
```

PS: I used list comprehension to make the code simpler.